# Switching between Gaming Desktop and Office Laptop

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse, ubuntu-16.04, multiple-computers

**The situation:**
Currently I'm running Windows 10 on my Desktop with

- Logitech G910
- Logitech G700s
- Logitech G930
- 2x BenQ RL2455HM

At the same time I'm working with Ubuntu 16.04 using my HP EliteBook Folio G1 at home.

**What I want to achieve now is** that I can switch between them using my Logitech Mouse, Logitech Keyboard, Logitech Headset and my main monitor (second one not needed with laptop "nice to have") on Laptop OR Desktop. 
Not to forget that I want to keep the features of my gaming hardware too when switching to my Desktop running Windows 10 (recognized by LGS), on Laptop running Ubuntu these features aren't needed.

I would prefer any kind of hardware solution as getting it done over network might give me some lag but I'm amenable to advice.

Use this image for clarification:

[image]

Comment: So you want to switch peripherals from one computer to another? You may want to reword it not really clear what you are asking.

Comment: @Confuzing Yes! I want to use my mouse, keyboard, headset and one monitor for both devices being able to switch between them at any time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [KVM switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch) will let you use one **K**eyboard, **V**ideo output and **M**ouse with two computers.

Keep in mind that KVM switch can affect latency which can have an impact on gaming.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want a KVM switch.

There are several models that support USB devices. Some even include support for headsets.

found one on [New egg](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817145110&cm_re=bytecc_kvm-_-17-145-110-_-Product)

You'll have to check your specific devices and the inputs supported by the KVM.